# Watson Text To Speech not using spanish voice nor accented characters

Tags: watson-text-to-speech

I cannot make Watson Text To Speech speak up in any language other than English (like Spanish, for example) event though it works on IBM's demo page (https://text-to-speech-demo.ng.bluemix.net).

The CURL shown below always use an american english voice, even though the voice "es-ES_EnriqueVoice" is explicitly specified, generating an audio file that sounds strange:

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Voice: es-ES_EnriqueVoice" \
--header "Accept: audio/wav" \
--data "{\"text\":\"Hola mundo\"}" \
--output myAudio.wav \
"{url}/v1/synthesize"
```

My 2 questions are:

1. does anyone know to make Watson speak using a voice that is not English (like Spanish, for example) in a POST like above? (btw: I could make it speak using another language other than English using a GET, instead of a POST), but I could not solve the next question (see below).
2. if you succeed on the question 1 above, can it speak a word that has accented character, like "opción"?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Accept: audio/wav" \
--data "{\"text\":\"Hola mundo\"}" \
--output myAudio.wav \
"{url}/v1/synthesize?voice=es-ES_EnriqueVoice"
```

bye